# What will happen if the highest bit of the pointer as a sign bit,can someone make a example to explain it?

Tags: windows

I am reading the book <windows via c/c++> ，in Chapter 13 - Windows Memory Architecture -
Getting a Larger User-Mode Partition in x86 Windows

I occur at this:

> In early versions of Windows, Microsoft didn't allow applications to
> access their address space above 2 GB. So some creative developers
> decided to leverage this and, in their code, they would use the high
> bit in a pointer as a flag that had meaning only to their
> applications. Then when the application accessed the memory address,
> code executed that cleared the high bit of the pointer before the
> memory address was used. Well, as you can imagine, when an application
> runs in a user-mode environment greater than 2 GB, the application
> fails in a blaze of fire.

I can't understand that, can someone make an example to explain it for me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To access ~2GB of memory, you only need a 31 bit address. However, on 32 bit systems, addresses are 32 bit long and hence, pointers are 32 bit long.

As the book describes, in early versions of windows developers could only use 2GB of memory, therefore, the last bit in each 32-bit pointer could be used for other purposes, as it was ALWAYS zero. However, before using the address, this extra bit had to be cleared again, presumably so the program didn't crash, because it tried to access a higher than 2GB address.

The code probably looked something like this:

```c
int val = 1;
int* p = &val;

// ...

// Using the last bit of p to set a flag, for some purpose
p |= 1UL << 31;

// ...

// Then before using the address in some way, the bit has to be cleared again:
p &= ~(1UL << 31);

*p = 3;
```

Now, if you can be certain that your pointers will only ever point to an address where the most significant bit (MSB) is zero, i.e. in a ~2GB address space, this is fine. However, if the address space is increased, some pointers will have a 1 in their MSB and by clearing it, you set your pointer to an incorrect address in memory. If you then try to read from or write to that address, you will have undefined behavior and your program will most likely *fail in a blaze of fire*.

Comment: thanks,another question," they would use the high bit in a pointer as a flag that had meaning only to their applications",what's the "applications" mean?windows api and Kernel? or the program like firefox? someone tell me Manipulating pointers is undefined behavior.

Comment: @ffxxee Application refers to whatever their program is, could be firefox, a game, or whatever else. You know, like phone apps. And yes, usually, manipulating pointers leads to undefined behavior (which often lead to crashes), but this is a specific example where this is not the case, but only for the MSB!